# Trimming start of Cstring without copying

Tags: c++, c, c-strings

I managed to get my homework to work but It shouldn't work because i have not finished it. I don't know why it does. I need help.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

char* trim(char* str) {
    const int lenStr = strlen(str);
    int characters = 0;
    bool trimmableFront = false;
    int firstChar;

    //check if trimmableFront + location of first char
    for (int i = 0; i < lenStr; i++) {
        if (*(str + i) != ' ') {
            if (characters == 0)
                firstChar = i;
            characters++;
        }
        if (characters == 0) {
            trimmableFront = true;
        }
    }

    //trim Front //THIS PART SHOULD BEHAVE DIFFERENTLY
    if (trimmableFront) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lenStr; i++) {
            if((firstChar + i <= lenStr))
                *(str + i) = *(str + firstChar + i); 
        }
    }
    return str;
}


int main() {

    char str[] = "       why does it work?";
    trim(str);
    cout<< str <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

At the end of trim(*char) function, trimmed string should have still leftovers from previous locations. 
For some reason it is perfectly trimmed and works as intended printing "why does it work?" but it should print something like "why does it workt work?"

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: yes and suddenly at the critical line it gets "truncated" into desirable output when it exits from last for loop

Comment: If does anything suddenly, you are not **stepping through** your code. Step through it line-by-line., while observing values of all local variables.

Comment: You’re copying the terminating zero.

Comment: How is this a C++ question?  You're not using any C++ objects, other than cout in main().  The only thing about the trim function that's not pure C is that you declare the for loop counter variables in the for statements.

Comment: @DanKorn and using  cout

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo ! I know now why it works partly. I dont know how it works under the hood but ill figure something out with google probly.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Im stepping through line by line and it really gets suddenly truncated as soon as it exits out of the for loop.

Comment: It's certainly C++ and not C. If you make a minimal example out of it that uses nothing that C doesn't have, it's still C++. And maybe C also. The declaration of the loop variable is actually C, though, C99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it works is because as you trim the string by shifting each character you also shift the terminating null character `'\0'`. As you probably know c-strings are array of characters terminated by `'\0'`, so as you print `str` with `cout` all characters are printed until the null value is reached: that is way the leftovers are not printed.

Comment: Is there any way to iterate over leftovers to see it with my own eyes?

Comment: @newUser As you step through the code, you'll see on the last iteration of the second loop that `*(str + firstChar + i)` contains the value 0.  Once that gets copied over, the string is terminated and the point where the 0 is.  Any bytes in the array after that don't matter.

Comment: @newUser well if you want to print those leftovers for dubugging reasons you can either replace <= with < inside the for loop to get the whole string. Or just cout << str+lenStr+1 to print only the leftovers.

Comment: @dbush apparently so because i tried to get them like this after the second loop: `int leftovers = 5;
  for (int i = 1; i < leftovers; i++) {
   cout << *(str + lenStr + i);
  }`                                                                                                        I thought going over the '\0' would give me those but they are already lost apparently

Comment: @newUser One doesn't need to "iterate over leftovers", to see that they are, actually, there. One can open memory window (or equivalent) in a debugger, navigate to the location of the array, and look at what is, actually, stored in memory.